# CMake ignores $CC and $CXX?

Tags: opencv, cmake, environment-variables

I am trying to compile OpenCV from source on Windows 10 because I thought this to be the way to incorporate [the surface matching module](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d9/d25/group__surface__matching.html) into the library. I tried to follow the installation instructions [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html) but when I try to execute the `installOCV.sh` from inside the gitbash like described, it fails halfway when CMake tries to testcompile with the C and C++ compiler. The script output is this:

```
$ ./installOCV.sh
Already up to date.
Current branch master is up to date.
Already up to date.
Current branch master is up to date.
/c/lib/Build/opencv /c/lib
-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.17134.
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:131 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:131 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/lib/Build/opencv/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/lib/Build/opencv/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

and CMakeError.log displays the following (sorry German):

```
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R)-Buildmodul, Version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Der Buildvorgang wurde am 18.01.2019 15:09:13 gestartet.
Projekt "C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" auf Knoten "1" (Standardziele).
PrepareForBuild:
  Das Verzeichnis "Debug\" wird erstellt.
  Das Verzeichnis "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\" wird erstellt.
InitializeBuildStatus:
  "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" wird erstellt, da "AlwaysCreate" angegeben wurde.
ClCompile:
  CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
  TRACKER : Fehler TRK0005: Fehler beim Suchen von "CL.exe". Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.


C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(356,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" wurde mit dem Code 5 beendet. [C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]
Die Erstellung des Projekts "C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" ist abgeschlossen (Standardziele) -- FEHLER.

Fehler beim Buildvorgang.

"C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (Standardziel) (1) ->
(ClCompile Ziel) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(356,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" wurde mit dem Code 5 beendet. [C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]

    0 Warnung(en)
    1 Fehler

Verstrichene Zeit 00:00:00.26


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R)-Buildmodul, Version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Der Buildvorgang wurde am 18.01.2019 15:09:14 gestartet.
Projekt "C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" auf Knoten "1" (Standardziele).
PrepareForBuild:
  Das Verzeichnis "Debug\" wird erstellt.
  Das Verzeichnis "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\" wird erstellt.
InitializeBuildStatus:
  "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" wird erstellt, da "AlwaysCreate" angegeben wurde.
ClCompile:
  CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
  TRACKER : Fehler TRK0005: Fehler beim Suchen von "CL.exe". Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.


C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(356,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" wurde mit dem Code 5 beendet. [C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]
Die Erstellung des Projekts "C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" ist abgeschlossen (Standardziele) -- FEHLER.

Fehler beim Buildvorgang.

"C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (Standardziel) (1) ->
(ClCompile Ziel) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(356,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" wurde mit dem Code 5 beendet. [C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]

    0 Warnung(en)
    1 Fehler

Verstrichene Zeit 00:00:00.26


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R)-Buildmodul, Version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Der Buildvorgang wurde am 18.01.2019 15:09:14 gestartet.
Projekt "C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" auf Knoten "1" (Standardziele).
PrepareForBuild:
  Das Verzeichnis "Debug\" wird erstellt.
  Das Verzeichnis "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\" wird erstellt.
InitializeBuildStatus:
  "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" wird erstellt, da "AlwaysCreate" angegeben wurde.
ClCompile:
  CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue CMakeCCompilerId.c
  TRACKER : Fehler TRK0005: Fehler beim Suchen von "CL.exe". Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.


C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(356,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" wurde mit dem Code 5 beendet. [C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]
Die Erstellung des Projekts "C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" ist abgeschlossen (Standardziele) -- FEHLER.

Fehler beim Buildvorgang.

"C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (Standardziel) (1) ->
(ClCompile Ziel) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(356,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" wurde mit dem Code 5 beendet. [C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]

    0 Warnung(en)
    1 Fehler

Verstrichene Zeit 00:00:00.28


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R)-Buildmodul, Version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Der Buildvorgang wurde am 18.01.2019 15:09:15 gestartet.
Projekt "C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" auf Knoten "1" (Standardziele).
PrepareForBuild:
  Das Verzeichnis "Debug\" wird erstellt.
  Das Verzeichnis "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\" wird erstellt.
InitializeBuildStatus:
  "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" wird erstellt, da "AlwaysCreate" angegeben wurde.
ClCompile:
  CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue CMakeCCompilerId.c
  TRACKER : Fehler TRK0005: Fehler beim Suchen von "CL.exe". Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.


C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(356,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" wurde mit dem Code 5 beendet. [C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]
Die Erstellung des Projekts "C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" ist abgeschlossen (Standardziele) -- FEHLER.

Fehler beim Buildvorgang.

"C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (Standardziel) (1) ->
(ClCompile Ziel) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(356,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" wurde mit dem Code 5 beendet. [C:\lib\Build\opencv\CMakeFiles\3.13.3\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]

    0 Warnung(en)
    1 Fehler

Verstrichene Zeit 00:00:00.27
```

Obviously neither `$CC` nor `$CXX` are taken into consideration by CMake, although they exist:

```
$ echo $CC
c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe

mark@zws103 MINGW64 /c/lib
$ echo $CXX
c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
```

PS: of course there could be some problem with spaces in filenames, but I tried gcc with a no-space path and the result was literally the same.

```
$ $CC
bash: c:/Program: No such file or directory

mark@zws103 MINGW64 /c/lib
$ "$CC"
Microsoft (R) C/C++-Optimierungscompiler Version 19.11.25508.2 f¦r x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Syntax: cl [ Option... ] Dateiname... [ /link Linkeroption... ]
```

Comment: Try not setting CC or CCX when using Visual Studio and see if it fixes the issue.  It probably interferes with the normal operation of Visual Studio tools like MSBuild.  Normally you don't need to set these variables.

Comment: I think that `$CC` and `$CXX` are not the correct environment variables. Set `$CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `$CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` instead.

Comment: @BHawk sorry, doesn't change anything. Same error :(. I deleted the whole tree so that no leftovers in a cache file would cause problems.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: @BHawk VS 2017 Enterprise

Comment: You will need to change the line in installOCV.sh to reflect that: `CMAKE_CONFIG_GENERATOR="Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"` should be changed to `CMAKE_CONFIG_GENERATOR="Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"`

Comment: @BHawk This combination didn't work either. But `12 2013` which I have installed alongside does indeed work. The question is if the CMake generator is broken for 2017 or my installation is so uncommon. I didn't change anything during the installation of 2017 tho.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186932/discussion-between-bhawk-and-vroomfondel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake is a two step process. The first step creates a set of makefiles or project files that can be used by the compiler. In this case you want to create MS Visual Studio project files.

The basic CMake commands are:

```
cmake <path to CMakelists.txt"> -G "<the type of compiler I want to use>" [Lots of other parameter options]
cmake --build <path to project files> [lots of other options]
```

The first line creates the build files needed by the compiler. The generator flag `-G` specifies the compiler being used. The project file creation also searches for any needed libraries, etc to ensure that the build will work.

The second line does the actual compiling.

The InstallOCV.sh script just sets up a lot of these params for you but it is essentially doing the above two calls in a slightly more complicated way.

Answer (score -1):

Try and download C and C++ compilers via MinGW.
The files would be named gcc.exe and g++.exe for C and C++ respectively. Add them to the environment path variable and then execute your shell file.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but my question specifically targets an installation with Visual C++ under the hood. I at least wanted to try and go this route because the (big) part of my application which will not be image processing, is deeply rooted in a .NET environment and I am so new to the field that I didn't want a gap between those two parts, for debugging reasons. If this is silly, please tell me.

Comment: can you add a picture of the components you've installed in your visual studio?